# order by case using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| 1 | Ramesh   | 32 | Ahmedabad | 2000.00 |
| 7 | Muffy    | 24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
| 6 | Komal    | 22 | MP       | 4500.00 |
| 2 | Khilan   | 25 | Delhi     | 1500.00 |
| 3 | kaushik  | 23 | Kota      | 2000.00 |
| 5 | Hardik   | 27 | Bhopal    | 8500.00 |
| 4 | Chaitali | 25 | Mumbai    | 6500.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

And, I am using the following query to sort the table as per my preferred order, but I am getting the following SQL error:

> CURSOR OPERATION CONFLICT

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY (CASE ADDRESS WHEN 'DELHI'   THEN 1
WHEN 'BHOPAL'   THEN 2
WHEN 'KOTA'   THEN 3
WHEN 'AHMADABAD' THEN 4
WHEN 'MP'  THEN 5
ELSE 100 END) ASC, ADDRESS DESC
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I've formatted your code for you but please edit your question and remove all of the CAPITALS.

Comment: And mark your response as answered ! You asked 5 questions, none is properly closed !

Answer (score 3):

Since Access does not suport CASE...WHEN, you have two options to get a custom sort order.

1) If you can edit the database structure, add a "SortOrder" column to the table.

Assuming the "Address" field has unique values in the "CUSTOMERS" table, create a field in the "CUSTOMERS" table called "SortOrder", specifying "1" for "Delhi", "2" for "Bhopal", and so on:

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMERS
ORDER BY CUSTOMERS.SortOrder DESC;
```

However, if it"s possible for the same "Address" value to appear multiple times in the "CUSTOMERS" table, you should create a new table like "ADDRESSES" that contains the Address and SortOrder values. The SQL would ultimately look like this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.* 
FROM CUSTOMERS INNER JOIN ADDRESSES ON CUSTOMERS.Address = ADDRESSES.Address 
ORDER BY ADDRESSES.SortOrder DESC;
```

2) Alternatively, if you can"t edit the database structure, using the IIf() function in the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMERS
ORDER BY IIf([ADDRESS] = 'DELHI',1,IIf([ADDRESS] = 'BHOPAL',2,
IIf([ADDRESS] = 'KOTA',3,IIf([ADDRESS] = 'AHMADABAD',4,
IIf([ADDRESS] = 'MP',5,6))))) DESC;
```

You should avoid doing this unless you can't edit the database structure because function calls are slow, especially when multiple conditions are evaluated as in this example. If you need to specify any additional sorting for the "ADDRESS" field, you will need to add additional IIf() functions, which will slow this down even further.

If you're able to specify a sort order for every value of "ADDRESS", you should use a single Switch() function instead of nested IIf() functions.

Comment: Tried the above query gettig the error 'insufficient memory'

Comment: also tried the switch command   ORDER BY  switch (cable_type = 'image 1000', 1, cable_type = 'cat 6a' , 2) same error as above 'insufficient memory'

Comment: Is your data exactly as you presented it at the top of your question? I created a table using that data in a test database and was able to sort it correctly using the SQL I provided.

Also, where did these cable type/cable_type fields come from?

Comment: the data is of the same type only the address column is replaced by cable_type column, but the main aim is to sort the data

Comment: SELECT * FROM MASTER_SCHEDULE_PEO
 WHERE RACK_A Is Not Null  AND RACK_B Is Not Null And EQIUPMENT_KRONE_IDA Like '%%WB 8%%'  Or RACK_A Is Not Null  AND RACK_B Is Not Null And EQIUPMENT_KRONE_IDB Like '%%WB 8%%'
 ORDER BY IIF([CABLE_TYPE] = 'IMAGE 1000',1,IIF([CABLE_TYPE] = 'CAT 6A',2,IIF([CABLE_TYPE] = 'IMAGE 360',3,4)))

Comment: Yes about 1500 records

Comment: In Access you use the asterisk character (*) as the general wildcard character, not the percent sign (%). You use the question mark (?) when you need to limit a wildcard to a specific character or a series of question marks for multiple specific characters, not the underscore (_).

This assumes you're using the Access/JET database engine.

Comment: So the SQL you posted in the previous comment has improper syntax. The `'%%WB 8%%'` should either be `'*WB 8*'` or `'??WB 8??'` depending on if you are searching for a string with "WB 8" anywhere with in it or if you only want 8 character strings that have "WB 8" as the third through sixth characters. (Unless the strings are actually '%%WB 8%%' and you are not using % as a wildcard character?)

Comment: SELECT * FROM MASTER_SCHEDULE_PEO ORDER BY IIF([CABLE_TYPE] = 'IMAGE 1000',1,IIF([CABLE_TYPE] = 'CAT 6A',2,IIF([CABLE_TYPE] = 'IMAGE 360',3,4)))

Comment: now i have change it to the above query but i am having the same error message insufficient memory code 40968 SQLSTATE A008. Can some other syntax be used to do the same job

Comment: If you can't find a way around the memory errors, you'll need to redesign your database with a sort column as outlined in the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`CASE` does not exist in Access. You can use `Switch()` instead.